# How to control Label text in SSRS report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I create SSRS stacked bar chart.The report show like as,

[image]

In **Y Axis** the account name will show I need to control that label's text.
which means I need enough to show first 10 letters from the Account Name.

For ex:Let Assume the account name is **SampleAccountNameABCConsultancy**

I need to show the **SampleAcco** instead of **SampleAccountNameABCConsultancy**.How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In chart data properties click CateGory Groups prerties-general-label .In that label expression use the following expression

```
=IIF(Fields!accountname.Value="",Fields!accountname.Value,left(Fields!accountname.Value,10))
```